# wifi and Sim network discontinuing on running my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

When I am running my app in iPhone for testing, **SIM** and **WiFi** network is connecting and disconnecting again and again.
 But in normal condition and running other app it is working fine?

I am using GPS and Map services in my app.

1)Problem in code? 
2)Problem in iPhone? 
3)Other?

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
    #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

    @interface MainViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate, 

    MKMapViewDelegate>
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mapView;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mkMap;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *myCurrentLocation;
    - (IBAction)mapView:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)mapToMain:(id)sender;
    @end






    #import "MainViewController.h"
    #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
    @interface MainViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation MainViewController
    @synthesize mapView;
    @synthesize mkMap;
    @synthesize myCurrentLocation;
    @synthesize locationManager;
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


        //start core location services
        if(self.locationManager == nil)
        {
            locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        }
        locationManager.delegate=self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        mkMap.showsUserLocation=YES;
        myCurrentLocation=mkMap.userLocation.location;

    }


    #pragma mark- core location delgate method
    -(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray         *)locations 
    {
        NSLog(@"locationUpdated");
        NSLog(@"%@",[locations lastObject]);
    }
    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (IBAction)mapView:(id)sender {

        [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    }
    - (IBAction)mapToMain:(id)sender {
        [mapView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    @end
```

Comment: How would anyone know it's a "problem in code" without seeing the code?

Comment: Please provide more detailed information.

Comment: If that happens only during running an application then problem is somewhere in your code otherwise device has issue.

Comment: @Adam, It's happing with me in all type of app like simple core data app in which I am just saving the detail.

Comment: @AbhishekGour Check ANY OTHER Maps App on your device; if the same problem persists, then your device may have problem.

Comment: @Matt, I have downloaded an app from itunes that using gps, Now same problem is occurring in this app but the MAP that is provided by Iphone is not    giving the problem.

Comment: @AbhishekGour Detailed comment is in Answer. Check that, now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check ANY OTHER Maps App on your device; if the same problem persists, then your device may have problem.

If same problem is occurring in this app, (**Which is your case**); AND MAP that is provided by Iphone is not giving the problem.

THEN, Consider checking the same App, you downloaded from AppStore for checking purpose, on some other device and see if the same problem persist.

If the problem **does not** exist on other devices then, your **device** is problematic.
If the problem **does** exist on other devices then, **code** you wrote is problematic.

Comment: thanx for solution I think there is some problem in my device.